# How can I get the maximum length of a textView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, textview

Hello
I created a textview in the main layout, with a certain value for android:maxLength. Now I'd like to get that value back into an int variable; I know how to refer to the textView in Java, but there are no direct methods in the TextView Object to get its maximium length. Is there any way to obtain this value?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. When you set maximum length what actually happens is that a new `InputFilter.LengthFilter` is created and added to input filters of this field. You can retrieve all the filters of this `TextView`, but even if you find this particular filter, you can't find out what was the maximum size.

Comment: Really? Can't we query the information from `InputFilter.LengthFilter`?

Comment: No, the only method it has is `filter`. Maximum length is stored in a private field with no access methods. I can think of a way to find out this value empirically by calling `filter` method, but this is tricky.

Comment: Did you see this?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength

Comment: Of course, I understand what you're trying to do, if that's what you mean.